# Vent near HVAC is very loud

Tags: hvac

There's a bathroom much closer to the HVAC unit than the rest of the vents and it gets tremendous air flow and is very loud. What could I do here? I was thinking perhaps some sort of airflow limiter at this vent (like a blob of insulation or something).

The vent is a fixed-louver 6" x 10" and looks like the duct is 4". It's on the ground floor of a two story home and the ductwork is not readily accessible, I would have to cut open the ceiling to install an inline damper. It looks like there are two runs leaving the blower - one goes to the laundry room and bathroom, the other to the great room and kitchen.

Here's a pic of the ducts leaving the heater unit
[image]

Comment: An inline damper would work wonders for reducing the airflow. Unfortunately there are no quick-fix and cheap solutions for reducing the noise.

Comment: Please revise to provide more information about the duct run, the vent louver, etc. We're in the dark here.

Comment: Well, it should be no surprise that the vents closest to the HVAC motor are the loudest...